# Bad "read more" behavior, trying to fix by inserting tag

Tags: read-more

Seems that others would have had this same problem with WordPress "Read More" but looking through previous questions with that tag did not help, so posting here.

As a new self-hosted WordPress user, I selected a wordpress.com theme I liked (Isola) but now have a "bad user experience" with it.  The problem: with a WP "Read More" tag in the post, clicking the link jumps into the full post at a place *below* the expected position, giving several unread lines above the screen view and so hidden. This behavior is screen width dependent - all works as expected for a narrow screen, as on a mobile device, but as the screen widens first one, then two, then three lines are hidden.

The hidden text confuses to the reader, since things suddenly begin in mid sentence - he somehow has to figure out that (1) there are missing lines in what he is reading and (2) he needs to scroll *upward* to read them.   FWIW the post begins with a narrow image with text flowing to its right and I am inserting the "read more" tag after the first paragraph.  I am unsure if browser formatting might be a factor - but this behavior occurs for both Chrome and Firefox and IE.

I do not want my blog readers to have this bad experience!  I don't know PHP but know coding so thought it would not be too difficult to create a better experience - by having the jump go to the top of the text (and also inserting a "hr" tag at the break point to make that more obvious).  This requires (1) altering the "more" link tag and (2) inserting a new anchor tag.  I have successfully created php to do the first.  But my attempt at (2) is not working.

I looked over the WP "hooks" to find something relevant - but there are nearly 2700 "hooks".  I tried to insert the anchor tag where I see a ".entry-header" html comment in the page source with the following code.  But I there is no change in the full post page source.  So I am doing something wrong and am looking for some more experienced help here.

```
function add_more_tag($content) {
        $content = preg_replace('/<!-- *\.entry-header *-->/', '<span id="more-000"></span>', $content);
        return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_more_tag', 20, 1);
```

Alternatively, I'd like to know if anyone has another way of correcting the basic "bad user experience" I described!  Personally I am very disappointed with the way that this aspect of this theme works (and I've been told this behavior also occurs for other wordpress.com themes).

PS: I know there is a plugin which removes the "more" link - that is the first thing I tried.  But the jump then goes to the top of the post, i.e. *above* the banner.  The banner is large and takes up much room, so I'd prefer the jump to go *below* the banner, i.e. at the top of the text.

Comment: Looking around some more, found content-single.php and seems like I could simply hard-wire a '<span id="more-000"></span> into that.  Will experiment with that.

Comment: Later - found that the above works, but would like to hear comments by others more knowledgeable than I before marking this "solved".  FYI current result is at blog.bigsurtrailmap.net   Note that now the "more" anchor at top of text and for a wide display the first text line(s) are hidden - but the "after the jump" paragraph is fully displayed, which is what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used to force the "continue reading" link to jump to the top of the text, just below the title

I first modified an existing "more" tag to a specified one -
in my style's functions.php, at its end I added

```
// ALTER MORE TO JUMP TO SPECIFIED TAG (which is above post text in content-single.php)
function alter_more_jump_link($link) {
    $moreoffset = strpos($link, '#more-');
    if ($moreoffset) { 
      $link = preg_replace( "/#more-[0-9]+/", "#more-jump", $link );
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'alter_more_jump_link', 20,1);
```

To insert the specified "more" tag after the title,
in my style's content-single.php, after line

```
</header><!-- .entry-header -->
```

I added

```
<span id="more-jump"></span>
```